# As a caster, is this homebrew crossbow worth using?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I am an 8th level Mystic Theurge (3Wiz, 3Cleric, 2MT). My DM gave me a homebrew belt-fed auto-reloading crossbow- 3 attacks per round at 1d10 each. Our party rogue declined it due to feats being just for bows.

The question is, can I make it worth my while to actually use this weapon instead of simply casting Lightning Bolt?

I have a +2 Dex and no Str modifier. I am an Elf.

It seems like if I cast Gravity Bow and a couple other buffs the damage could be high. However I cannot help but feel that my attack rolls would be too low to really hit anything- my BAB is nothing to write home about. Furthermore the low duration and high spell slot usage of the buffs means I'd pay a lot for a short time.

I neglected to mention one small detail: ammunition. The homebrew crossbow requires some homebrew ammunition. 500gp for 30 bolts (at 3 bolts per round) and the supply is highly limited at best. I would need to use Abundant Ammunition (repeatedly) to keep firing it.

I have Extend Spell available to extend the duration.

I suppose that actually, my current BAB is +4, and my dex is another +2. So that's a flat attack roll bonus of +6, which I suppose is not really that bad for 8th level?

Comment: What's the value of the crossbow were it to be sold?

Comment: Good question. I have a massive Appraise skill so I can Appraise the xbow next session. It is, in fact, Pathfinder.

Answer (score 4):

## Sell the crossbow... *probably*

I don't know the rules for the belt-fed fully automatic crossbow your DM homebrewed, but a level 8 character who takes a standard action to make an attack roll and, if successful, deals 3d10 points of piercing damage isn't living up to his potential, [mystic theurge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/core-rulebook/mystic-theurge) or not.

Any resources invested in making that crossbow better will probably cut into resources that would be better spent on making your casting better, and as a mystic theurge, you need to make your casting count.

Sell the crossbow. Use that money to scribe more spells into your spellbook or something.

This assumes a purely mechanical perspective, though. If possession of this crossbow, for example, marks you as The Chosen One or as leader of the Fraternity of Killers, then it'd be a good idea to keep it anyway. DMs don't often take time to homebrew unimportant stuff, so you might want to research the weapon's provenance before vending it.

Comment: So far, I have yet to encounter any higher meaning to the crossbow. It was likely conceived as a temporary in-joke, as we all remembered about six sessions after the fact that my character actually has a ring of arrow deflection *and* a vest of arrow deflection, so when the opponent used this crossbow it was stupendously ineffective. I promptly looted it off his defeated body (which is yet another in-joke).

Comment: @Puppy A campaign-specific in-joke may be an even *better* reason to keep the weapon, especially if you take every opportunity to do stupid tricks with it. ("Look," says the wizard, "you can *try* to threaten us with arrows and crap, but, really,..." And, with that, the wizard shoots himself thrice in the head with his fully automatic crossbow... to no effect. "You should just probably give up now.") The reason to play is to have fun, and, if the crossbow is a reminder of how much fun the game is, you *should* keep the crossbow.

Comment: @Puppy Also it might be worth keeping in case you ever run into an area where you are unable to cast or have to be careful how many of your spells you use because you will not have time to rest.

Answer (score 2):

### In short, Yes...

A crossbow couldn't get a benefit from a strength mod, so it's an ideal ranged option for your stats.

In longer battles or with many battles in a day, your spell slots are a limited resource, doubly so if you're the primary healer, and your cleric spells will be burned to patch people up and keep the party going longer.

When a fight comes along where your current spell preparation isn't useful/necessary, whip out the crossbow.

While Gravity Bow isn't a bad buff for it's level, see if you can't get Heroics (3.5 Spell Compendium) for your second level wizard buff option. It has a better duration, better versatility, allows you to vary the effects to the situation, and can help you dive the Weapon Focus feat chains for additional accuracy.

If **to hit** is a major concern, see if you can't squeeze the Zen Archery feat into your build at level 9. Not only will it allow you to replace Dex with Wis (one of your casting stats) on attack rolls with the crossbow, it will also be the stat used on all ranged attack rolls, including the rays of disintegration you're firing from your Wizard side.

Comment: I am not the primary healer or damage dealer, but we are a party of only three and I typically play quite a flexible role (our other caster can cast healing spells and Fireball and that's mostly it). In fact, I am even the party tank. My primary concern is mostly whether or not I'll actually be able to *hit* things with the xbow- being able to fire it when I'm out of slots is of little use to me if I can't make the attack rolls I'll need.

Comment: Updated to include solution to the to hit problem that's versatile enough to not only be good for the crossbow.

Answer (score 0):

1. Mechanically, it's probably not as effective as your spells, as described in Hey I Can Chan's answer.
2. But it could be really fun. See the comments in Hey I Can Chan's answer, because it has party memories involved. So I wouldn't use it by default or put a lot of effort into making it effective. But it might be handy if three attacks/round is what you need.
3. Do you *want* it? If you *want* it to work, you can ask the GM, I want to keep this in the campaign, but it's not worth using at the moment. Can we invent improvements my character can research to make this more effective but still balanced? Many GMs will jump at adding an interesting character quirk the campaign. If they say "no", then either they intended it as a throw-away idea and don't mind if you keep it, or they think you're wrong about the mechanical effectiveness.